# Issues with Include Errors in VSCode

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, sfml

I recently started reading Beginning_C++_Game_Programming. I'm following along attempting to make a Timber knock-off but I can't seem to get my environment set up properly.

The error:

```
PS C:\Program Files\VS Projects\Timber\source_files> g++  Timber.cpp
Timber.cpp:6:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

The code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    // Create video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);

    // Create & open game window.
    RenderWindow(vm, "TTimber!", Style::Fullscreen);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried adding the path to the 'includepath' in the properties.json file

```
"includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:/Program Files/SFML/**"
        ]
```

But I'm still getting the error, I've also tried using the -I argument with gcc to make it work...

```
g++ -I C:\'Program Files'\SFML\include\SFML Timber.cpp
```

But it's still not seeing the header file. What really confuses me is the fact that VSCode is giving me info on the commands included in the header file while editing code. So it must  be using the file, but can't use it during compilation for some reason. See below.

[image: Without Include]

Without the include line the commands linked by the header get underlined as errors/unknown commands, but when I add the include line it knows what they are. So it MUST be seeing the header file to some extent...
[image]

So how can vscode know that these are actual commands but the compiler can't find the file during compilation? Any help here would be greatly appreciated, I've spent the last couple of hours tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: ***But I'm still getting the error, I've also tried using the -I argument with gcc to make it work*** That is actually required. `c_cpp_properties.json` is settings for intelisense only. `tasks.json` is for building. You need to specify the include path in each of these 2 separate files.

Comment: I don't see a tasks.json anywhere... is that something I need to create?

Comment: Should be in the .vscode folder. Related: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)